# How to fix 'Index was outside the bounds of the array' in C#

Tags: c#

can you possibly help me and tell me how to fix the error message "Index what outside the bounds of the array" in C #? I'll post the code below. The error message is: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array in line 504 and 505 and i marked this lines as // THIS LINE

```
public void HandleConnectionData(ref byte[] data)
        {
            if (data[0] == 64 || data[0] == 33)
            {
                int pos = 0;

                while (pos < data.Length)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (data[pos] == 64)
                        {

                            int MessageLength = Base64Encoding.DecodeInt32(new byte[] { data[pos++], data[pos++], data[pos++] }); // THIS LINE
                            uint MessageId = Base64Encoding.DecodeUInt32(new byte[] { data[pos++], data[pos++] }); // THIS LINE

                            if ((MessageLength - 2) > (data.Length - pos))
                            {
                                return;
                            }

                            byte[] Content;

                            try
                            {
                                Content = new byte[MessageLength - 2];

                                for (int i = 0; i < Content.Length; i++)
                                {
                                    Content[i] = data[pos++];
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                Logging.LogException("HandleConnectionData #1 Error: " + e.ToString());
                                return;
                            }

                            ClientMessage Message = new ClientMessage(MessageId, Content);

                            if (this.MessageHandler == null)
                            {
                                this.InitHandler();
                            }

                            if (Message != null)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    Logging.LogPackets2("[" + this.UInt32_0 + "] --> [" + Message.Id + "] " + Message.Header + Message.GetBody());

                                    if (int.Parse(Phoenix.GetConfig().data["debug"]) == 1)
                                    {
                                        Logging.WriteLine("[" + this.UInt32_0 + "] --> [" + Message.Id + "] " + Message.Header + Message.GetBody());
                                    }
                                }
                                catch { }

                                Interface @interface;
                                if (Phoenix.smethod_10().Handle(Message.Id, out @interface))
                                {
                                    @interface.Handle(this, Message);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else if (data[pos] == 33)
                        {
                            ++pos;

                            int MessageLength = Base64Encoding.DecodeInt32(new byte[] { data[pos++], data[pos++], data[pos++] });

                            if (MessageLength > (data.Length - pos))
                            {
                                return;
                            }

                            byte[] Content;

                            try
                            {
                                Content = new byte[MessageLength];

                                for (int i = 0; i < Content.Length; i++)
                                {
                                    Content[i] = data[pos++];
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                Logging.LogException("HandleConnectionData #2 Error: " + e.ToString());
                                return;
                            }

                            try
                            {
                                CustomEventHandler.HandleEvent(this, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Content));
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                Logging.LogException("HandleConnectionData #3 Error: " + e.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Logging.LogException("Error #1: " + e.ToString());
                        this.Disconnect();
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (data[0] == '<')
            {
                this.Connection.SendData(CrossdomainPolicy.GetXmlPolicy());
                this.Connection.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You current try catch blocks are highly questionable as you swallow fatal exception and go on after exceptions in general. Also you have a half dozen of them in one piece of code. Fix that so you actually have the information you need to debug it. Here are two articles on the mater: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: You shoulde check length with pos before using data[pos]